# Is it possible use a button for submit form and ajax request in asp.net MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've made a web crawler it has to check a website and get some value for adding into database. I've used quartz.net for scheduling on that website.  because my crawler every 20 seconds has to check it. So,I have not problem so far. but I my problem that is when I want to submit form and ajax request the same time.My form send Index action in `HomeController` but my ajax request goes to `GetData` action method in `HomeController` In fact,my ajax request has to get last data from `GetData` action method and also.when I click on satrt button for submitting my form it submit to index action but when click the same button that is defined in `jquery` code it submit null to `GetData` action method.because before that my form is submitted to Index action method and my Inputs is null.
finally,I want to know how to use a button for submit my form and ajax request?
or what is your solution for my issue?

> I've used this way but it isn't suitable for this issue.
>
> I've changed type="submit" to "button" that my form is not submitted
>   to index action method.

[image: My Project]

```
public JsonResult GetData(ScrapJob scrap)
{
    var fetchData = db.Scraps.Where(s => s.Url == scrap.Url && s.Keyword == s.Keyword).Max(s => (int?)s.Id) ?? 0;
    var findData = db.Scraps.Find(fetchData);
    return Json(findData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

---

```
$(function () {
    var timeoutFunction;
    var scrapForm = $("#scrapForm").serialize();
    $("#btnStart").click(function () {
        timeoutFunction = setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/GetData",
                data: scrapForm,
                success: function (data) {
                    var rows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + data.Url + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.Keyword + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.DateTime + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.Count + "<td/>" + "</tr>";
                    $("#scrapTable tbody").append(rows);
                    //alert(data.Url);
                    //console.log(data.Url + ":" + data.DateTime + ":" + data.Keyword + ":" + data.Count);

                }

            });
        }, 1000);
    });

});
```

---

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "scrapForm" }))
{
    <div class="container container-table">
        <div class="row verticla-center-row">
            <div class=" col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="keyword" class="control-label">Keyword</label>
                    <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control" id="keyword" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Url" class="control-label">Url</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Url" class="form-control" id="Url" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" id="btnStart" class="btn btn-success">Start</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<table id="scrapTable" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Url</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Keyword</th>
            <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody></tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: `btnStart` button type should be `submit`.

Comment: what problem you are facing in ajax code?Not aware about `.Net`

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question and if your code is really working, this change will do what you want. With your `btnStart` as button:

```
$(function () {
    var timeoutFunction;
    $("#btnStart").click(function () {
        var scrapForm = $("#scrapForm").serialize();
        $("#scrapForm").submit();
        timeoutFunction = setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/GetData",
                data: scrapForm,
                success: function (data) {
                    var rows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + data.Url + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.Keyword + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.DateTime + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.Count + "<td/>" + "</tr>";
                    $("#scrapTable tbody").append(rows);
                    //alert(data.Url);
                    //console.log(data.Url + ":" + data.DateTime + ":" + data.Keyword + ":" + data.Count);

                }

            });
        }, 1000);
    });

});
```

PS: Your `GetData` is expecting an object and you cannot pass object through `GET` request. Change the HTTP method of your method to `POST`

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetData(ScrapJob scrap)
{
    var fetchData = db.Scraps.Where(s => s.Url == scrap.Url && s.Keyword == s.Keyword).Max(s => (int?)s.Id) ?? 0;
    var findData = db.Scraps.Find(fetchData);
    return Json(findData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You may need to use `JSON.stringify(scrapForm)` to send the data

if you want to use `GET` request you'll to change the method signature to accept your `Url`and `Keyword` separately and then pass then on your request
`"/Home/GetData?url=urlValue&keyword=keywordValue"`

Comment: Yes, you got that right,but GetData action method works just the first time but ajax request has to pass every 1 second for calling GetData action method and also my form submit to Index action method correctly but I still have problem with send ajax request every 1 second to GetData Action method.

Comment: it's really hard to understand what your problem really is but if I understood right, just save your form data in a session. On the first time you submit, you store the data in this session, then you check the session value, if it's not null, you set `scrapForm` to the session value (previous submitted data) and that's it